# Create new dataset using existing dataset by adding null column in-between two columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a dataset in Spark using Java by reading a csv file. Following is my initial dataset:

```
+---+----------+-----+---+
|_c0|       _c1|  _c2|_c3|
+---+----------+-----+---+
|  1|9090999999|NANDU| 22|
|  2|9999999999| SANU| 21|
|  3|9999909090| MANU| 22|
|  4|9090909090|VEENA| 23|
+---+----------+-----+---+
```

I want to create dataframe as follows (one column having null values):

```
+---+----+--------+
|_c0| _c1|     _c2|
+---+----|--------+
|  1|null|   NANDU|
|  2|null|    SANU|
|  3|null|    MANU|
|  4|null|   VEENA|
+---+----|--------+
```

Following is my existing code:

```
Dataset<Row> ds  = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "false").load("/home/nandu/Data.txt");
Column [] selectedColumns = new Column[2];
selectedColumns[0]= new Column("_c0");
selectedColumns[1]= new Column("_c2");
ds2 = ds.select(selectedColumns);
```

which will create dataset as follows.

```
+---+-----+
|_c0|  _c2|
+---+-----+
|  1|NANDU|
|  2| SANU|
|  3| MANU|
|  4|VEENA|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the two columns you want and add a new one with nulls you can use the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType;

ds.select({col("_c0"), lit(null).cast(DataTypes.StringType).as("_c1"), col("_c2")});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Following code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ lit => flit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val ds = spark.range(100).withColumn("c2",$"id")
ds.withColumn("new_col",flit(null: String)).selectExpr("id","new_col","c2").show(5)
```

Hope this Helps

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding new column with string null value may solve the problem. Try the following code although it's written in scala but you'll get the idea:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
val ds2 = ds.withColumn("new_col", lit(null).cast(StringType)).selectExpr("_c0", "new_col as _c1", "_c2")
```